# What should be the dims of labels in tensorflow Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am confused with this situation and would appreciate if someone could help me:

I have my inputs and outputs with these shapes:

x_train shape is: (4793, 212, 129) and y_train shape is: (4793,)

```
y_train: tf.Tensor([8 5 5 ... 7 6 3], shape=(4793,), dtype=int64)
x_train:   ...
  [ 2.2921903e+00  2.1890440e+00  1.8762966e+00 ... -1.4906397e+00
   -1.4929566e+00 -1.4934100e+00]
  [ 2.7695382e+00  2.6324050e+00  2.1426291e+00 ... -1.1090920e+00
   -1.1087614e+00 -1.1089599e+00]
  [ 2.1462238e+00  2.3000312e+00  2.0514350e+00 ... -1.2017721e+00
   -1.2031162e+00 -1.2032846e+00]]], shape=(4793, 212, 129), dtype=float32)
```

I want to create a dataset out of this: So I wrote this function:

```
def create_ds(x, y, batch_size):

  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))

  # Batch dataset
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)

  # Use buffered prefecting
  return ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

And then create my training dataset by train_ds = create_ds(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128). So when I print train_ds I get:

```
<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 212, 129), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int64)>
```

But I am not sure how I should define my model: I tried:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(212, 129))
x = Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1))(inputs)
# More layers here
x = Flatten()(x)
# More layers here
output = Dense(len(label_to_class), activation="softmax")(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, output)
```

And I am using Adam and as a loss sparse_loss_categorical (my label is a number from 0 to 9), like this:

```
model.compile(
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

model.summary()
```

But when I fit my model: `history = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=validation_ds, epochs=2)`

It's not working:

```
Epoch 1/2
38/38 [==============================] - 6s 153ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.1018 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1002
```

I think it has to do with the dimensions of my labels: (None,) but I already tried adding a new dimension so it becomes (None, 1) but it did not work.

As suggested in the comments, here is the summary of the model:

```
Model: "model_14"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_15 (InputLayer)        [(None, 212, 129)]        0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_14 (Lambda)           (None, 212, 129, 1)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_56 (Conv2D)           (None, 210, 127, 32)      320       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_56 (Batc (None, 210, 127, 32)      128       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_56 (Activation)   (None, 210, 127, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_56 (MaxPooling (None, 105, 63, 32)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_57 (Conv2D)           (None, 103, 61, 64)       18496     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_57 (Batc (None, 103, 61, 64)       256       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_57 (Activation)   (None, 103, 61, 64)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_57 (MaxPooling (None, 51, 30, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_58 (Conv2D)           (None, 49, 28, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_58 (Batc (None, 49, 28, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_58 (Activation)   (None, 49, 28, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_58 (MaxPooling (None, 24, 14, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_59 (Conv2D)           (None, 22, 12, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_59 (Batc (None, 22, 12, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_59 (Activation)   (None, 22, 12, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_59 (MaxPooling (None, 11, 6, 256)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_14 (Flatten)         (None, 16896)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_28 (Dropout)         (None, 16896)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_28 (Dense)             (None, 128)               2162816   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_29 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_29 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,553,866
Trainable params: 2,552,906
Non-trainable params: 960
```

Comment: It would be great if you add the `model.summary()` output.

Comment: Thanks @Kaveh I just added the model summay, do you think it has to do with the dims of my labels? Which are (None,) but I tried to add and axis so they become (None, 1) but still did not work

Comment: None is ok. None means the shape may be anything. Your shape and code looks OK. Nothing prone to error observed. Have you checked your data for __null__ values? Or are you sure you have labels limited between 0 and 9?

Comment: @Kaveh I would say the dataset has not null values and labels are between 0 - 9, I am working with tfds: specifically the [GTZAN](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/gtzan) and I've been exploring it and it seems ok: 10 genres... I did a lot of preprocessing, extracting log spectrograms, normalizing, etc... maybe something there but when I print and example of x_train or y_train, seems to be ok to me

Comment: I double check with this: `tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(x_train))` `<tf.Tensor: shape=(0, 3), dtype=int64, numpy=array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=int64)>` and  `tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(tf.cast(y_train, tf.float32)))`  `<tf.Tensor: shape=(0, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=array([], shape=(0, 1), dtype=int64)>`... still getting `10/10 [==============================] - 15s 1s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.1001 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1052`